# getting an error with javascript when I try to pass my website on Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

First sorry for my english.

Im trying to upgrade my website from bootsrap 2 to bootstrap 3 and this cause me an error with the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Livret/CSS/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //mise en route d'alert
        $(".alert").alert();

        //affichage de formulaire au clique sur ligne du tableau
        $("tr:has(td):not(:has(th))").dblclick(function(){
            var idModal = "#myModal".concat($(this).find("input:hidden").val());
            $(idModal).modal();
        });

        //affichage de formulaire au clique sur bouton
        $("#addCompo").click(function(){
            $("#formAddComposante").modal();
        });
    });

</script>
```

When I click on my button and inspect the element with Chrome I have this error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-dismiss="alert"] ".

So I update my jQuery version from 1.9.1 to 2.1.0. So now I dont have any error but when I click on the button the screen goes dark but the window I was expected to appear is not here.

Anyone who knows how to solve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when upgrading to Bootstrap 3. Check the classes and structure in the HTML for your modal. It should look like this:

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals